# Survival models and differential equations

Tags: survival, differential-equations

I have a question regarding survival models and differential equations. Is it possible to translate survival models ( in survival analysis) into differential equations? For example can we write the [cox proprotional hazards model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model) $$ \lambda(t,X) = \lambda_0 (t) \exp(\beta 'X) $$ as a differential equation?

Comment: Why do you want this? Any context?